# Regex: issue with selecting multiple groups

Tags: php, regex

I need to make 3 groups out of the following text:

```
[startA]
this is the first group
 [startB]
 blabla
[end]
[end]
[startA]
this is the second group
 [startB]
 blabla
[end]
[end]
[startA]
this is the second group
 [startB]
 blabla
[end]
[end]
```

As you can see, each group begins with `[startA]` and ends with `[end]`, it should be easy to make a regex that matches this.
But the problem is that inside a group, the string `[end]` is used an arbitrary amount of times.
The regex should match a group that starts with `[startA]` and ends with the `[end]` right before the next `[startA]`, not a previous `[end]`.

I think it should be done with lookahead but none of my attempts have worked so far.
Is it possible to do this with a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you indeed may solve this with lookahead:

```
$test_string = <<<TEST
[startA]
this is the first group
 [startB]
 blabla
[end]
[end]
[startA]
this is the second group
 [startB]
 blabla
[end]
[end]
[startA]
this is the third group
 [startB]
 blabla
[end]
[end]
TEST;
preg_match_all('#\[startA](.+?)\[end]\s*(?=\[startA]|$)#s', 
    $test_string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Here's [**ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/TLKY6H).

The key is using alternation in lookahead sub-pattern, to test either for the next `[startA]` section, or the end of the string (`$`).

Note the `/s` modififer: without it `.` meta-character won't match endlines ("\n").

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursive regex pattern

```
preg_match_all('/\[(?!end)[^[\]]+\](?:[^[\]]*|[^[\]]*(?R)[^[\]]*)\[end\]\s*/', $s, $m);
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/XjHAbj)**.